# Are Srimad Bhagvatam and Srimad Bhagvad Mahapurana the same?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, vyasa

I have seen two books — *Srimad Bhagvatam* by Srila A.C. Bhaktivedant Swami Prabhupada and another named *Srimad Bhagvad Mahapurana* by Maharishi Vyasadeva. Are these two the same? I saw that the content isn't matching. Here's an excerpt from Srila Prabhupada's *Srimad Bhagvatam*:

**oḿ namo bhagavate vāsudevāya
janmādy asya yato 'nvayād itarataś cārtheṣv abhijñaḥ svarāṭ
tene brahma hṛdā ya ādi-kavaye muhyanti yat sūrayaḥ
tejo-vāri-mṛdāḿ yathā vinimayo yatra tri-sargo 'mṛṣā
dhāmnā svena sadā nirasta-kuhakaḿ satyaḿ paraḿ dhīmahi**.

This is the first chapter's first verse in Prabhupada's book. But the first chapter's first shloka in Vyasadeva's Bhagvad Mahapurana isn't matching. In a nutshell, are these different books?

*Source: Krsna App*

Comment: Welcome to the Hinduism SE! Both Srimad Bhagvatam and Srimad Bhagvad Mahapurana are the same composed by Vyasa. Swami Prabhupada translated Sanskrit text into English..Shloka should be same in both the text but it seems u saw shloka from Mahatmya, can you share the source where it's different..[Gitapress version](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_202003_176_d/page/n82/mode/1up) also have same shloka..

Comment: Are are you referring to the [Gita Press English translation](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/page/n5/mode/2up) which begins with 'Bhāgavata Māhātmya'? It clearly says it's extracted from Padma Purana. The actual translation begins from [page 49](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/page/n61/mode/2up).

Comment: Srimad is just a title (like Mr. Sir, Shri etc.) it is found before any other Puranas. Also, Bhagavatam and Bhagavata Purana refer to the same text.

Comment: See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54871/is-krishna-mentioned-in-the-first-verse-of-srimadbhagavad